# Homomorphism of formal group of elliptic curve corresponding to its endomorphism

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, power-series, formal-groups

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve and $ \hat{E}$ be its formal group.
Rubin's lemma $3.7$ in 'Elliptic curves with complex multiplication' reads

> For arbitrary $φ∈End(E)$, there exists unique $φ(t)∈End( \hat{E})$ such that
> $φ((x(t),y(t)))＝(x(φ(t)),y(φ(t)))$.

How can I find such $φ(t)$ and it's unique ?
If this is famous formal group fact, reference is also appreciated.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the questions, but it seems to me that this is just a change of variables. If $\varphi$ is given by two rational functions $\varphi_1(x,y)$ and $\varphi_2(x,y)$ with $\varphi(x,y) = \bigl(\varphi_1(x,y),\varphi_2(x,y)\bigr)$, then $t \mapsto - \varphi_1\bigl( x(t),y(t)\bigr)/ \varphi_2\bigl(x(t),y(t)\bigr)$ is the endomorphism of the formal group.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that is the only candidate for $φ(t)$. But how can I prove $φ(t)$ is homomorphism of $ \hat{E}$ ? I'm at a loss to prove the equation  $φ( \hat {E}(x,y))＝\hat {E}(φ(x),φ(y))$.